# Is there a way to extract a subset of a dictionary

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary from a json file but all I have tried did not work.

```py
json_file = [
    {'original_block': '94.142.136.0/21',
     'transferred_blocks': '94.142.136.0/21',
     'from': 'MAROSNET Telecommunication Company LLC',
     'to': 'NTX Technologies s.r.o.',
     'date': '28/06/2019',
     'transferType': 'POLICY'
    },
    {'original_block': '185.2.4.0/22',
     'transferred_blocks': '185.2.4.0/22',
     'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.',
     'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.',
     'date': '01/07/2019',
     'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION'
    }
]

new = ['original_block', 'date']

newd = {key:value for key,value in json_file.items() if key in new}

print(newd)
```

it gives an error message `'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

I expect

```py
newd = {'94.142.136.0/21': '28/06/2019', '185.2.4.0/22':'01/07/2019'}
```

Comment: Your `json_file` variable has many dicts in it. Do you want the values for all of them, or just the first one?

Comment: I've edited the question to emphasize the true nature of `json_file`.

Comment: i want all the values not the first one

Comment: `newd = {d['original_block']: d['date'] for d in my_json}`

Comment: Steven's post worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a comprehension with `dict`:

```
data = [{'original_block': '94.142.136.0/21', 'transferred_blocks': '94.142.136.0/21', 'from': 'MAROSNET Telecommunication Company LLC', 'to': 'NTX Technologies s.r.o.', 'date': '28/06/2019', 'transferType': 'POLICY'}, {'original_block': '185.2.4.0/22', 'transferred_blocks': '185.2.4.0/22', 'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.', 'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION'}]
new = ['original_block', 'date']
result = dict([c[i] for i in new] for c in data)
```

Output:

```
{'94.142.136.0/21': '28/06/2019', '185.2.4.0/22': '01/07/2019'}
```

Edit: as a precaution, a check with `all` can be used to ensure that missing values do not raise a `KeyError`:

```
dict([c[i] for i in new] for c in data if all(j in c for j in new))
```

Comment: Good answer. As an extra safeguard for situations where both keys are *not* in the json, replace `for i in new` with `for i in new if i in c`.

Comment: @agtoever Thank you. Your suggestion is a good one, and I added a possible implementation with `all`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `new` is always going to be two elements (since you are using the first element as key and the second element as value)

```
json_file = {'original_block': '94.142.136.0/21', 'transferred_blocks': '94.142.136.0/21', 'from': 'MAROSNET Telecommunication Company LLC', 'to': 'NTX Technologies s.r.o.', 'date': '28/06/2019', 'transferType': 'POLICY'}, {'original_block': '185.2.4.0/22', 'transferred_blocks': '185.2.4.0/22', 'from': 'REGISTER.IT S.P.A.', 'to': 'REGISTER S.P.A.', 'date': '01/07/2019', 'transferType': 'MERGER_OR_ACQUISITION'}
new = ['original_block', 'date']

newd = {dict_[new[0]]:dict_[new[1]] for dict_ in json_file if new[0] in dict_ and new[1] in dict_}
print(newd)
```

What the problem is that `json_file` is a list of dictionaries `[{},{}]`, not a dictionary `{}` so when you try to do `json_file.items()` it crashes because lists don't have a items() operation

Comment: What the user wants can only to for two items because he is taking in the first item as a key and the second item as value.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the sub-dicts in `json_file` to `operator.itemgetter` with the items in `new` as the keys to get, and pass the resulting sequence of 2-tuples to the `dict` constructor:

```
from operator import itemgetter
newd = dict(map(itemgetter(*new), json_file))
```

`newd` becomes:

```
{'94.142.136.0/21': '28/06/2019', '185.2.4.0/22': '01/07/2019'}
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple one-liner:

```
newd = {d[new[0]]: d[new[1]] for d in json_file}
```

Comment: This is not the expected output that the user wanted

Comment: Fixed, should be ok now :)

Answer (score -1):

```
newd = {}
for dic in json_file:
    newd.update({dic[new[0]]:dic[new[1]]})
```

[image]

Comment: No need to create and discard dictionaries to pass to update when you could just assign to a key.  This just unnecessarily complicates things with no compensating benefit.